# facebook group feeds android

Tags: android, facebook, rss

I am trying to get a facebook feed from a group. I am confused as how to do this. Does this mean the person has to login first to access it or will there be some sort of RSS Feed that keeps getting updated that I can use and read in directly.

Thank you for your effort and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Graph API do a HTTP(S) Post to `{groupId}/feed`

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Comment: Sure, you can go to the Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and test it there. When you get to that page you will see your id in that tester.  Just add `/groups` to it an click get.  Select one of the group ids displayed and replace your id with the group id and add `/feed` then click get again.

Comment: thank u i follow as u said i am getting  my group list and details. i want to display only groups list in android emulator can i know what is the procedure

Answer (score 1):

Use a wallflux feed: just give the facebook group id in http://wallflux.com and it should work?

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ID+"/feed?access_token="+mFacebook.getAccessToken();
```

By parsing the above link using Json Parsing we can get the feeds of the group.
ID :id of the group of which we want the feeds.

the output we got a json object and then we use json parsing to get different posts.